# Updating the data on Firebase Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to update the date on Firebase on a specific node.

DB Structure:

[image]

I am trying as

```
private void updateData() {
database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
myref = database.getReference();
myref.child("myDb").child("awais@gmailcom").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        dataSnapshot.getRef().child("leftSpace").setValue(newValue);
        dialog.dismiss();
        
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d("User", databaseError.getMessage());
    }
});
}
```

I want to update the `leftSpace` key with the value of `newValue`, `newValue` is the type of string here. But it is not updating the value in Firebase.

If I give here

```
dataSnapshot.getRef().child("leftSpace").setValue(765);
```

it updates well. But I want to update in the format of string on the Firebase.

I saved the data on Firebase of all string types. (My pattern class contains all of the type strings)

Why it is not updating the `newvalue` of type string here?

**Edit 1** Suggested by @Rjz Satvara

You method is adding a new node under `myDB` as

[image]

It is not updating the already one.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In **Firebase** To update specific value you can use it...

```
ref.child("myDb").child("awais@gmailcom").child("leftSpace").setValue("YourDateHere");
```

or you can move into child using "**/**" as follow :

```
ref.child("myDb/awais@gmailcom/leftSpace").setValue("YourDateHere");
```

Comment: Not working. it is making a new node. See the Edit 1 in question.

Comment: Still not working. It is adding a new node of name `leftSpace` under the `myDb` node. (`myDb` is my DB name). See where I am . I run the code as `myref.child("CarParki").child("awais@gmailcom").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                try {
                    myref.child("awais@gmailcom").child("leftSpace").setValue("YourDateHere");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }`

Comment: yup.. congratulation and thank you.. happy Sharing , keep learning and Enjoy

Comment: You can pass the entire path as one string. So this shorter code accomplishes the same: `ref.child("myDb/awais@gmailcom/leftSpace").setValue("YourDateHere");`

Answer (score 4):

According to Firebase Official Documentation you can update the specific node of parent node in this way

> Using setValue() in this way overwrites data at the specified location, including any child nodes. However, you can still update a child without rewriting the entire object. If you want to allow users to update their profiles you could update the username as follows:

```
    FirebaseDatabase  database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference mDatabaseRef = database.getReference();

    mDatabaseRef.child("TABLE_NAME").child("orderStatus").setValue(2);
```

Note! TABLE_NAME mean your parent node whose child node you want to update.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

you can assign new value in same child,like

```
  Firebase firebase = new Firebase("your database link/myDb");
    firebase.child("awais@gmail.com").child("leftSpace").setValue("newValue");
```