# Updating recyclerview on firebase using dialog

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, updates

My purpose is this:

I'm making a `TaskList`. In the Tasklist I have a `RecyclerView`, and the items of the `RecyclerView` I'm storing on Firebase. So far everything worked perfectly.

Now I want the following thing to happen: when I am clicking on an item it opens a dialog that let the user update the date of the current task.

I have 2 problems:

1. the `TaskKey` always returns the first Taks's key.

   the First problem I solved using Final in this line:

   ```
   final String TaskKey = getRef(position).getKey();
   ```
2. The field I'm trying to update wont get updated, it's only getting created as a new task inside the first item on the Firebase Database.

I tried reading this as well, but it didn't work for me:
[Updating the data on Firebase Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41296416/updating-the-data-on-firebase-android)

Structure:

[image]

This is what i have been trying so far:

```
public class TaskList extends AppCompatActivity {
    DatePicker datepicker;
    ImageView edit;
    private RecyclerView mListRV;
    public DatabaseReference mTaskRef;
    String mDay, mMonth, mYear;
    int mtime;
    public DatabaseReference mRef;
    String TaskKey;
    Button updateTask;
    Dialog dialog;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_task_list);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        mTaskRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Tasks");

        mListRV = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.list_rv);
        mListRV.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mListRV.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Tasks");

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter < Task, TaskViewHolder > firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter < Task, TaskViewHolder > (

                Task.class,
                R.layout.item_layout_task,
                TaskViewHolder.class,
                mTaskRef.orderByChild("time")

        )

        {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(final TaskViewHolder viewHolder, Task model, int position) {

                TaskKey = getRef(position).getKey();

                viewHolder.SetProf(model.getProf());
                viewHolder.SetNum("מטלה מס':" + " " + model.getNum());
                viewHolder.SetDate(model.getDay() + "/" + model.getMonth() + "/" + model.getYear());

                viewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        dialog = new Dialog(TaskList.this);
                        dialog.setTitle("עדכון זמן מטלה");
                        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.updatedate);
                        dialog.show();

                        datepicker = (DatePicker) dialog.findViewById(R.id.datepick2);
                        updateTask = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.UpdateButton);

                        mtime = 0;
                        mMonth = String.valueOf(datepicker.getMonth());
                        mYear = String.valueOf(datepicker.getYear());
                        mDay = String.valueOf(datepicker.getDayOfMonth());
                        mtime = Integer.parseInt(mDay);
                        mtime = mtime + (Integer.parseInt(mMonth)) * 31;
                        mtime = mtime + (Integer.parseInt(mYear) - 2000) * 365;

                        updateTask.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                UpdateTask();
                            }
                        });

                    }
                });

            }
        };

        mListRV.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
        //mTaskRef.orderByChild("time");

    }

    private void UpdateTask() {

        DatabaseReference NewTask = mRef.child(TaskKey);
        NewTask.child("year").setValue(mYear);
        NewTask.child("month").setValue(mMonth);
        NewTask.child("day").setValue(mDay);
        NewTask.child("time").setValue(mtime);
        Toast.makeText(this, TaskKey, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //Toast.makeText(this,"המטלה עודכנה בהצלחה", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        dialog.dismiss();
    }


    public static class TaskViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        View mView;

        public TaskViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mView = itemView;

        }

        public void SetProf(String prof) {
            TextView profT = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.textProf);
            profT.setText(prof);
            ImageView color = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.ProfColor);
            switch (prof) {

                case "מבוא לכלכלה":
                    color.setBackgroundColor(mView.getResources().getColor(R.color.calcala));
                    break;

                case "מערכות הפעלה":
                    color.setBackgroundColor(mView.getResources().getColor(R.color.hafala));
                    break;

                case "תפי":
                    color.setBackgroundColor(mView.getResources().getColor(R.color.tapi));
                    break;

                case "נושאים מתקדמים":
                    color.setBackgroundColor(mView.getResources().getColor(R.color.mitkadmim));
                    break;

                case "מימוש מערכות":
                    color.setBackgroundColor(mView.getResources().getColor(R.color.mimusha));
                    break;

                case "מודלים חישוביים":
                    color.setBackgroundColor(mView.getResources().getColor(R.color.modelim));
                    break;




            }
        }

        public void SetNum(String num) {
            TextView numT = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.textNum);
            numT.setText(num);
        }

        public void SetDate(String date) {
            TextView dateT = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.textDate);
            dateT.setText(date);
        }

    }


    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    }


    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_add) {
            startActivity(new Intent(TaskList.this, AddTask.class));
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you share database structure

Comment: i update the Struct

Comment: i manage to solve my first problem using Final, but still having a hard time with my second problem